# Generating context samples relative to the embedding relation/edge value of the respective entity?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, embedding, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to build my own corpus / text dataset to train a domain specific `NER`. My entities are primarily numerical based and partially rely on context to be classified. There is no specific dataset suitable for my case. Thus, I'm generating my own texts and contexts.

The idea I had in mind was to generate contexts based on words of which the embedding is similar to the entity I want to classify. Making sure the context keeps changing to keep the model generic and doesn't overfit on specific words.

A comparable example (not my specific case) would be: Trying to tag IP addresses in texts. My idea is to find all words related to the text embedding of the word `IP` or `computer`. A similar embedding would, for example, be `software` with an `0.8` edge value.

My question is:

- How can I easily extract similar words from an embedding layer (e.g. word2vec?). And how would I determine the cutoff point? List all words from highest similarity to lowest and manually determine a cutoff point (when I consider the word not similar enough as context for the entity `ip address`). Or would an automated process be enough? Extracting all words until a specified cutoff point, for example, of `0.8` similarity edge /relation value.
- How many samples should I generate relative to the word similarity of the entity? E.g. I generate 100 sample texts for the entity `IP address`, should I then only generate 80 context samples based on the word `software` as it has an `0.8` similarity edge / relation value to `ip address`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to answer because it's so abstract. It's not clear what the actual domain is; there are no examples of your 'pseudotexts'; there are no interim results from things you've tried, and found lacking, against which to make suggestions-for-improvement.

Because there are no pat answers for a problem at that level of underspecification, you will likely have to try some things, and then review the mix of encouraging & unsatisfying results (& possibly share here), to discover possible useful thresholds for similarity-levels or pseudo-text-generation counts.

For example, the similarity values from such models, even though they always are in the `-1.0` to `1.0` range, don't map well to human concepts of "X% similar". If you change model metaparameters, tokens might still have very similar "top 10" neighbors, but with wildly different cosine-similarity values. (The rank ordering can be far more significant/stable than the raw cosine-similarity numbers, at least until you decide to freeze some aspects of the model metaparameters & training data.) So there's no way for anyone to recommend a threshold like `0.8`, or even be sure any such threshold makes sense, without more domain/model/end-goals specific experimentation. (At which point, *maybe* some project-specific thresholds could be discovered, in absolute cosine-similarities or top-percentiles of all similarities or certain neighbor-lists.)

Similarly, for generating synthetic text samples, there's not fixed answers. You need true variety reflecting the subtleties of the underlying domain. 1000 samples are no better than 100 if they're nearly identical repeats – you could just repeat the 100 samples 10 times each, or increase the model's training 'epochs', to get the same effect – but without true variety in the data the model won't learn more. So again, you'll need to iteratively experiment on your data, model, & end-usefulness goals.

Some have applied word2vec-like algorithms to giant graphs by creating their 'texts' from random-walks, of various lengths, through the graph. How such walks are created – i.e. whether a particular 'node'/unique-token 'should' appear dozens, hundreds, or thousands of times in the training data – could be influenced by how important that node/token is in the downstream applications, how much real variety there is in its in- and out- edges, etc. So again, it's a matter for experimentation & trial-and-error.